# In SharePoint 2010 - Does SPSiteCollection.Add create the default groups?

Tags: site-collection

Referring to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b73dd31b-1ec9-4f44-8cb2-80b2f6796eb5

Does SharePoint 2010 create default groups when site collection is created pro grammatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SPWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.createdefaultassociatedgroups.aspx) method on your root web to create default Owner and Visitors groups.

Comment: i am aware of the method to create the default  group. My question was is the issue resolved in SharePoint 2010 or not.

Comment: In SP2010 this issue isn't resolved, after creating site collection you have to use this method to create default groups.